# who is owner in association with jpa and hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am confused in owner in relationship with hibernate.

what exactly is owner(owner side) in association?

I want to study Mappedby and inverse.
please help.

Comment: mkyong.com is a good start

Comment: @яша Stop suggesting random site. Link official docs if you have.

Comment: Here you go :http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqi

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ whether it is official or not the main thing is to understand the concept! who cares if the official docs is offering 1000's of pages of philosophic words while what I need are 2-3 pages to help me solve my problem ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ then why people still trust sites like stackoverflow ?! you believe people in the official documentation do not make mistakes ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As a general rule the owning side of a relation would the side which you'd need to update for the change of the relation to be persisted.

If you are mapping the entities to a relational database (most probably the case) the owning side often can be identified as the entity whose table contains the foreign key.

In the entities themselves `mappedBy` would refer to the owning side and thus is placed on the inverse side of the relation.

In 1:n relations in most cases the owning side is the *n* side, in n:m relations, 1:1 relations or 1:n with mapping tables you can choose either side, just choose one.

Example:

```
class Thread {
  @OneToMany( mappedBy = "thread" )
  List<Entry> entries;
}

class Entry {
  @ManyToOne
  Thread thread;
}
```

In the example, the owning side would be the `Entry` entity, since you need to change the value of `Entry#thread` to change the thread an entry belongs to. Just adding/removing an entry to/from `Thread#entries` wouldn't make the changes persisted in most cases (`orphanRemoval` and the like would still have an effect if done correctly).